# How can I refactor a type of error move field?

Tags: java, refactoring, simplify

I'm reading the types of error in Code Smells and trying to understand in the category Inappropriate Intimacy,

I found the solution move field. Can someone exemplify and explain me that solution "Move field"?

I found something in https:[refactoring.guru/move-field](https://refactoring.guru/move-field) but I still do not understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example field `MOVE_ME` is used only in different class (MyRealUssage). so you can move it:

```
public class Unused {
   public String moveMe = "This is used only in other classes"
}

public class MyRealUssage {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println(new Unused().moveMe);
  }  
}
```

Move field will update valid field location:

```
public class Unused {

}

public class MyRealUssage {
  public String moveMe = "This is used only in other classes";    
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println(new MyRealUssage().moveMe);
  }  
}
```

Obviously a better code will also removing unused `Unused` and use getter for field,as

```
public class MyRealUssage {
  public String moveMe = "This is now used only this class";    
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println(getMoveMe());
  }  
  public String getMoveMe() {
     return moveMe;
  }
}
```